# Failed to load resource: SSL peer certificate or SSh remote key was not OK

Tags: .net, angular, playwright

I am developing an application with angular and .net. I happen to be testing the angular application with playwright.
The test they need to pass is to pass the login screen. It turns out that when I click on a button to make the login request to the back in chronium and firefox it works great but in webkit I get the following error:

Failed to load resource: SSL peer certificate or SSh remote key was not OK.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why this happens and I don't know if it is because with webkit I have to configure something additional when I make the request to the back.

Please someone help me to solve this mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's an issue of your tests - try to use **ignoreHTTPSErrors** in playwright.config

```js
 use: {
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
 },
```

per browser

```js
projects: [
    {
      name: "Desktop Safari",
      use: {
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      },
    },
  ]
```

or in test directly

```js
test.use({
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});
```